# Using a US/UK voltage transformer at low end of appliance power range

Tags: voltage, transformer, watts

I've purchased [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/VitaClay-VM7900-6-Smart-Organic-Clay-Multi-Cooker-Requires-US-to-UK-Transformer/233496432131?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) from ebay, and the official vitaclay product spec page for the model indicates a power consumption range of 500-600W.

Transformers appear to come in either 500W or 1000W, but nothing in between. What does it mean that the product spec indicates a range of 500-600W input? Does it mean that it consumes different amounts of power depending on the functionality that is used with it? Can I use a 500W transformer with it? (For example, [this one](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/500W-Step-Up-Down-Voltage-Converter-Transformer-Transformer-Converter-UK-US/283464183793?hash=item41ffc82ff1:g:o-4AAOSwxupcwmMb)?) What happens if it attempts to draw power at a rate exceeding 500W?

Comment: It's not good linking to ebay - link to the actual manufacturer's site and their specifications.

Comment: Thought experiment: your house and your neighbours' are supplied by the utility company's transformer which will have a certain power rating. What will happen if everyone switches off all the appliances in their houses? What will happen if you all switch everything on at the same time and draw more than the utility transformer is rated for?

Comment: @Andyaka eBay is as close as you'll get. This is all no-name junk from the usual Pacific Rim country. It's not like we're dealing with Siemens here.

Comment: The official web site is mentioned but not linked @Harper-ReinstateMonica

Comment: @Andyaka I was referring to the transformer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pull 600W through a 500W transformer, it won't really care for about the first 5 minutes.  It's overheating, but between the copper and iron it has so much thermal mass it will take awhile to reach any temperature of concern.  But then, it will start to overheat. Eventually you will burn up the varnish on the transformer windings, then coils will start to short circuit, causing funny things to happen to current and voltage, and either causing weakening or a thermal runaway situation where it creates more heat, causing more internal shorts, causing more trouble, iteratively until it pops a circuit breaker.

Further, you have your eye on cheap Cheese junk type transformers that have gone straight from Alibaba to eBay.  Nothing from those, Banggood, AliExpress, DealExtreme, Amazon Marketplace, etc. etc. can legally be connected to AC mains.  These are built as cheaply as possible, completely ignoring safety and consumer product codes, such as electrical safety (e.g. thick enough wires to work reliably; good insulation), flammable materials, toxicity of materials when burnt, quality cords, fuses in cords, safety of sockets (those "everything sockets" are particularly unsafe, *especially for high current appliances*), etc. This is particularly important in the UK because you have 32A fuses on branch circuits, which means the fuse in the plug is absolutely essential for safety.

Of course there is no mark from a reputable testing lab like BSI, TUV or CSA.  There's a CE mark, but CE is a self-certification by the manufacturer or importer.  They are shipped straight from China (often via dropship warehouses like Amazon), which means **you're the importer**.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly 500/600 watt is a generality. Transformers are not that accurate. When you see a 500 watt rating that means it will stand at least 500 watts. Also transformers as you said come rated in steps i.e. 500, 750, 1000. You can always use a larger size as long as you have room to fit it. The actual rating usually comes from the wire size that the transformer is wound from. As for the 500/600 rating that usually derives from either the 50 or 60 cycle power that it is run on. It can in some instances come from the base supply voltage i.e. 110 vac or 120 vac and or a combination thereof. So you see it is not that critical or exacting, just make sure a transformer is always as big or a little bigger than the heaviest peak load that you intend to pull from it.